# Extracting source node name and destination node name from message or packet

Tags: omnet++

Extracting source node name and destination node name are required instead of IP address or MAC address in messages or packets, which may need to define a new message type that includes source node name and destination node name. For example, when a node named hostA send a packet to a node named hostB, a record such as ("hostA", "hostB", "packet154") is logged or output.

Comment: Do you require the names of hosts only for log purpose?

Comment: Dear @JerzyD. Yes, It is better to log packets by nodes name.

Answer (score 1):

That is already the case in the log window. [image: Message/Packet traffic] (at least in OMNeT++ 6 preview). Just switch to packet mode in the lower right corner.